# How to make Netbeans IDE have no whitespace between edge of editor and code?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, code-editor

I'm using Netbeans version 8.0.2

I've looked through all the indent/tab settings but I see no setting that will allow me to get rid of the space at the beginning. See the space between the lightbulb and the < less than sign. Anyone know how to make it so code goes right up to the left side of the code editor?

[image: Space in Netbeans]

**Update:**
I was able to reduce the space by going to View > Show Diff Sidebar and turning off/unchecking this. It reduced it but code is still not all the way to the left. If anyone has any other tricks to get it all the way to left, please let me know.

Comment: You need to turn off `Preferences > Editor > Code Folding`, `View > Show Diff Sidebar`, `View > Show Indent Guidlines`. Personally i wouldnt find this important enough to turn off all those features, but to each his own.

Comment: No, that is not it. Those are all off. I find it important because I find it annoying when seeing whitespace and like to know for certain I am at the start of the line.

Comment: I just double-checked and that worked for me, unless there is something else you have turned on that I do not. But Im pretty much using the defaults everywhere except in the code formatting settings.

Comment: Ahh what about `Preferences > Editor > General > Braces Matching`? Try unchecking both those options. Also if you keep code folding and braces matching enbaled you just need to look for the outermost outline - it will tell you where the beginning of the line is. Or you could turn on show whitespace so you can see tabs/spaces letting you know where the beginning is that way.

Comment: @prodigitalson You're a genius. Thank you so much. That did it. I checked my settings a million times and couldn't find it. Much appreciated!